# How Does Batibat Escape Aunt Zelda's Urn?

Tags: chilling-adventures-of-sabrina

In the beginning of Episode 5 of Season 1, Sabrina goes to her aunts for help with the demon Batibat, who she has unwittingly released from the Achernon Configuration. They help her by having Zelda capture Batibat in an urn, but Batibat tortures them in their dreams later that night. The Spellmans capture Batibat again using Hilda's spiders, but then they just put her back in a jam jar. How can they expect this jar to hold her if she escaped the urn?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the show, but between an urn and a jam jar... I'd think a jam jar would have a better, tight-fitting lid - suited to the extremes of jam processing.  It might, or might not be relevant (based on the show's details), but it's what I thought of.

Comment: The show never mentions anything like that. I don't think it fits the nature of CAoS. Thanks for the effort though.

Answer (score 1):

Batibat didn't escape from the urn - she was never captured. Right before Zelda seemingly traps her, Batibat attempts to make them fall asleep; while it seems she fails and is subsequently captured, she actually succeeded and then made the lot of them *dream* Zelda has managed to capture her.

At least that's what I believe we are supposed to think.